# Firefox text input truncates bottoms of letters

Tags: html, css, firefox

Drop below letters like g, y, j are truncated in Firefox 3.6 only.

```
<input type="text" value="yyyy gggg xxxx" style="height: 1em;" />
```

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/yqTjX/

My google-fu is completely failing me. Simple problem. I imagine there is a simple solution.

Comment: Are you sure you can't just do `height: 1.2em`? http://jsfiddle.net/yqTjX/7/

Comment: Client likes the smaller input boxes. So unfortunately I need a solution that does not involve making them larger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1em represents the width of a lowercase M in the given font, so I understand.  1em won't necessarily produce enough height for a full character to be displayed.  Because of differences in font rendering between browsers (especially Firefox and Safari), you may notice subtle differences along these lines.  Either remove the height (so it's automatically calculated), or increase the size.  Nice and simple.

Comment: My problem is that the client wants the textboxes not to take up too much room. If I increase the height of the input they don't like the look. I need the text height to match the input height.

Comment: Are you saying that if you take the "height" out completely, it's too large?  think about it the other way.  If you have no "height", then you can size the text, and the input will change its height to match.

Comment: Digitally speaking, it's actually the height of the font and it's set by the font itself, so it's actual pixel value, is determined by what font you're using.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. As you pointed out FF renders quite a bit differently from IE9/Webkit. It looks to me like input:height is useful when creating more space around existing font, however going smaller truncates letters. Instead font-size should be used when you want an input sized to the font you are using.

Comment: You're welcome, and I'm glad it helped.  The only thing I would say is that it's not just the engine that handles font rendering.  Webkit generated text under MacOS looks very different to Webkit generated text under Windows.  Either way, this way of doing it should set you in good stead :)

Answer (score 1):

don't use em's to size the input then you can then change the font-size to suit. If you set the size via em's the box will always be based on the font-size, it's inherited.

1em is usually (not always) always equivalent to 16px if the users browser default setting are at default or it will be based on a font-size setting you have set earlier in your sheet.. find the equivalent in px for your clients wishes and then make the font-size for those inputs about 3-4px smaller to allow  for the descenders and ascenders

```
input {  
    height: 16px;
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```